# Model Mixin for object history

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create a Mixin that will keep track of the history of an object/instance. The idea seems simple enough: override the models.Model's save method to grab the object before the change, save the change, and then compare to see which fields have changed and save the changes to another table:

```
class ObjectHistoryMixin(object):

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    previous_state = self.__class__.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
    super(ObjectHistoryMixin, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    new_state = self
    fields = self.__class__._meta.get_fields(include_parents=False)
    for field in fields:
        if getattr(previous_state, field.name) != getattr(new_state, field.name):
            print('field {} changed'.format(field))
```

I tried it on this model:

```
class Insurer(ObjectHistoryMixin, models.Model):

    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey('users.User', on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    name = models.CharField('naam', max_length=100)
```

But this doesn't work:

```
AttributeError at /portal/beheer/verzekeraars/9/bewerken/

'Insurer' object has no attribute 'submittedprescription'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/portal/beheer/verzekeraars/9/bewerken/
Django Version:     1.11b1
Exception Type:     AttributeError
Exception Value:    

'Insurer' object has no attribute 'submittedprescription'

Exception Location:     C:/Users/Administrator/SVN/doras_val\portal\models.py in save, line 20
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Administrator\SVN\venvs\venv_doras_val\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.6.0
Python Path:    

['C:/Users/Administrator/SVN/doras_val',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2016.3.2\\helpers\\pydev',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\SVN\\doras_val',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\JetBrains\\PyCharm 2016.3.2\\helpers\\pydev',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\SVN\\venvs\\venv_doras_val\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\SVN\\venvs\\venv_doras_val\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\SVN\\venvs\\venv_doras_val\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\SVN\\venvs\\venv_doras_val\\Scripts',
 'c:\\python36-32\\Lib',
 'c:\\python36-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\SVN\\venvs\\venv_doras_val',
 'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\SVN\\venvs\\venv_doras_val\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    di, 7 Mrt 2017 13:15:38 +0100
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/portal/beheer/verzekeraars/9/bewerken/

Django Version: 1.11b1
Python Version: 3.6.0
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'crispy_forms',
 'public',
 'users',
 'portal',
 'portal_patient',
 'portal_pharmacy',
 'portal_manager']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'portal_patient.middleware.ActivePatientMiddleware',
 'portal_pharmacy.middleware.ActivePharmacyMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\Administrator\SVN\venvs\venv_doras_val\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\Administrator\SVN\venvs\venv_doras_val\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\Administrator\SVN\venvs\venv_doras_val\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Administrator\SVN\venvs\venv_doras_val\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:/Users/Administrator/SVN/doras_val\portal_manager\mixins.py" in dispatch
  11.         return super(PermissionRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Administrator\SVN\venvs\venv_doras_val\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Administrator\SVN\venvs\venv_doras_val\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  240.         return super(BaseUpdateView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\Administrator\SVN\venvs\venv_doras_val\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in post
  183.             return self.form_valid(form)

File "C:\Users\Administrator\SVN\venvs\venv_doras_val\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\messages\views.py" in form_valid
  11.         response = super(SuccessMessageMixin, self).form_valid(form)

File "C:\Users\Administrator\SVN\venvs\venv_doras_val\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in form_valid
  162.         self.object = form.save()

File "C:\Users\Administrator\SVN\venvs\venv_doras_val\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in save
  451.             self.instance.save()

File "C:/Users/Administrator/SVN/doras_val\portal\models.py" in save
  20.             print(getattr(previous_state, field.name))

Exception Type: AttributeError at /portal/beheer/verzekeraars/9/bewerken/
Exception Value: 'Insurer' object has no attribute 'submittedprescription'
```

`submittedprescription` in this case has a ForeignKey to Insurer. It's very possible that I'm going about this the wrong way, so please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related fields may not be set as instance attribute when the object does not actually have such relation.

You'd probably better use a fallback value. For instance:

```
if getattr(previous_state, field.name, None) != getattr(new_state, field.name, None):
```

As an alternative, you may also rather want to exclude "one-to-many" relations:

```
fields = self.__class__._meta.get_fields(include_parents=False)
for field in fields:
    if not field.one_to_many and getattr(previous_state, field.name) != getattr(new_state, field.name):
        print('field {} changed'.format(field))
```

or exclude non-editable fields:

```
fields = self.__class__._meta.get_fields(include_parents=False)
for field in fields:
    if field.editable and getattr(previous_state, field.name) != getattr(new_state, field.name):
        print('field {} changed'.format(field))
```

Comment: Looks like I can't access `request.user` during the save, which is kind of the whole point, so I may have to try a different route after all... But your suggestions all work, thanks!

Comment: what's the point with request.user. How is it related to your question?

Comment: because I want to track which user made the change. But I guess that's not possible because the save may not always be triggered from an actual request but from the shell for example, which wouldn't have a user.

Comment: You didn't mention this in your question. Indeed you can't access `request.user` in you model. If you wish to do this yourself, best is to create generic views or mixins to handle recording.

Comment: yeah I realized this additional problem too late, but thanks for helping anyway!